# MacBook Touch Bar app launcher software?

Tags: osx, launcher, macbook

I'm really want to utilize Touch Bar as a application launcher for my brand new MacBook Pro 2016.

So far, I found few apps:

- [TouchSwitcher](https://hazeover.com/touchswitcher.html)
- [Rocket](http://julianthayn.com/rocket)

But two both is not suitable for my situation.

1. `TouchSwitcher` does not support sorting applications as dock.
2. `Rocket` does not support function that showing **opened apps** and **closed apps** at the same time on the same section (instead, it supports the function as another separated button or new section).

I'm looking for the application that shows the dock's apps on the touch bar (includes opened, closed apps).

Is there any usable Touch Bar app launcher that satisfies my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [App Pier.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-pier/id1179807827?mt=12)

It supports sorting apps. 
In addition you can view both pinned and running apps at the same time.